# Linux 'lsof' command return large value

Tags: linux, lsof, tomcat, open-files

I'm using a linux server with tomcat 9.0.24. When I stop the tomcat server,
following output will return for 'lsof | wc -l' command

```
fdmt@fdm-3-136 apache-tomcat-9.0.24]$ lsof | wc -l
1203
fdmt@fdm-3-136 apache-tomcat-9.0.24]$
```

If I start the tomcat server, 'lsof' command return a large number of open files. Refer to the below output segment.

```
[fdmt@fdm-3-136 apache-tomcat-9.0.24]$ lsof | wc -l
1203
[fdmt@fdm-3-136 apache-tomcat-9.0.24]$ ./bin/startup.sh
Using CATALINA_BASE:   /usr/local/tbx/fdmt/apache-tomcat-9.0.24
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /usr/local/tbx/fdmt/apache-tomcat-9.0.24/
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /usr/local/tbx/fdmt/apache-tomcat-9.0.24/temp
Using JRE_HOME:        /usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_271/jre
Using CLASSPATH:       /usr/local/tbx/fdmt/apache-tomcat- 
9.0.24//bin/bootstrap.jar:/usr/local/tbx/fdmt/apache-tomcat-9.0.24/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
Tomcat started.
[fdmt@fdm-3-136 apache-tomcat-9.0.24]$ lsof | wc -l
30492
[fdmt@fdm-3-136 apache-tomcat-9.0.24]$
```

This value is keep increasing slowly. I'm using Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server (VERSION=7.0)
Can anyone face the same issue?
Please advice if there is any solution for this issue.

Comment: Sorry, but what is the issue? Having 1000+ files opened on a system is not strange in any way.  My personal Ubuntu machine has over 5000 open files without it being an issue. You are also showing 30000+ files open when running Apache. Does this prevent you from doing anything in particular?

Comment: Yes, as I mentioned, open file count is 30492 just after start the tomcat. This value will keep increase 500,000+ over time. I have removed content in webapps folder inside the tomcat and still this value increasing. I'm wondering the reason to have 30492 files opend just after I start the tomcat.

Comment: Are you seeing actual errors somewhere?

Comment: No there were no issues on the logs, I have removed the .war files from the webapp folder. It's just tomcat and the libraries.

Comment: 100 java threads will display 100 times the same file opened, which will count only as 1 opened file. Using `| wc -l` can't help to see this.

Comment: @A.B Than you for your reply. I have did some analysis based on your reply and sort out the issue. I have add a detailed answer to my own question below.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the reason for the above issue with **@A.B**'s answer. I compared 'lsof' output after start tomcat instance in two Linux servers. One server return large value (Related to my original question) whereas the second server always return less than 2000.

The reason for the issue was having two different versions of 'lsof' in both server. (4.82 and 4.87) Latest version include results related to threads.

lsof-4.82: (No TID column)
[image]

lsof-4.87: (Have TID column)
[image]

Therefore, If there are 100 threads will display 100 times the same file opened, (As mention by @A.B) Which will count only as 1 opened file. But `| wc -l` return the number of duplicate rows for different threads. (Which indeed incorrect)

Comment: It's a pity that you buried the actual _issue_ (different numbers on two separate servers) in your answer rather than include it in the question.

Comment: @Kusalananda I didn't do that when I was posting the question. After A.B's reply I did the comparison with the old version of lsof. I was just include my findings in my answer